# Date issue in Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, angular-ui

I uses Angular UI Date picker. When i select the date **July 15 2015**, the model value assigned as follows (I am in India GMT +5:30)

```
 2015-07-14T18:30:00.000Z
```

Code i used for date picker

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="testDate" name="testDate" 
        ng-model="testDate" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" 
        is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" />
```

In the server side(in UTC format), when i access the date like **new Date('2015-07-14T18:30:00.000Z')**, it gives me the data as **14 July 2015** instead of **July 15 2015**

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is UTC time vs Local time when the 'day' of UTC time is different than the 'day' of Local time.

Try converting to local time on the server if you want to see local time.  It seems that if you were to +5:30 it would resolve to July 15 2015  at midnight.  So for UTC it is correct but local time it is incorrect as you need the +5:30.  I don't know what language you are running server-side but there should be a way to set the 'kind' of the date to local and specify a culture.

It's best practice to store time as UTC and only convert to local right before presenting it to the user.  So I would store it in the DB as '2015-07-14T18:30:00.000Z', and when retrieving the data just return ''2015-07-14T18:30:00.000Z' as whatever localtime you need.

Here is some code to auto change the model to local time:

```
  $scope.$watch('testDate', function() {
        $scope.testDate= $filter('date')($scope.testDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
  });
```

be sure to inject $filter into your controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understood. But is there any way to get Time Zone specific date in angular ui date timepicker instead of UTC date?

Comment: you will have to filter it with the date filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: but i want to have model value in local time zone format instead of UTC format?

Comment: I added some sample code to watch 'testDate' and transform to local time, check my edit above

Comment: Thanks it solves the issue. But i used filter in the api `save` instead of `watch`. Will that be okay? Why angular ui date does not provide this functionality?